# How to run Composer Update command for Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I have setup laravel on my localhost with all classes. It is running correctly on my localhost.

I have uploaded my code to my server. its working fine.

Now I have added some classes like

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

and alias

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

in my app.php file.

When I again run the url of my live server it gives me error like

```
Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found.
```

I think I have to update  my composer. But I am not able to run composer update command on live server.

Can any one tell me how can I make it run-able.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `laravelcollective/html` in your composer.json ?

Comment: Yes I have added that Like this ""require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
    },"

Comment: Do you have SSH of your server?

Comment: Yes, I have, Let me try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If composer ist not available in the command line you have the option to manually [download](https://getcomposer.org/download/1.4.1/composer.phar) the composer.phar and save it in the root folder of your application.

You can then run the command **php ./compser.phar install.**

If php is not available either or you don't have ssh access to your server at all, your only option is to manually upload the contents of your **vendor** folder manually....

Comment: I have done it using ssh and its working fine. Thanks for your answer.